# Instalar linux sin usb en sistema UEFI sin rufus

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows

estoy tratando de instalar linux hace como 5 meses y no puedo, tengo una notebook samsung que me dijeron que tiene uefi, mi disco duro al parecer también (no se mucho del tema, pero tiene arranque seguro). Ya use rufus, UNetbootin (este me tira error al iniciarlo), probe de muchas formas, con muchas distros pero ninguna funciono, hay alguna forma de hacerlo? Por ejemplo yo tenia W7 y pude montar la ISO de W10 e instalar windows 10, pero cuando monto una ISO de alguna distribucion no me sale la opcion para instalar, **puedo instalarlo desde el mismo sistema operativo W10** ?

Comment: 2 cosas: este no es el foro para esa pregunta. https://unix.stackexchange.com/ creo que es más apropiado.... y cual es el modelo?

Comment: Uh no tenia idea de eso, gracias por avisar. El modelo es np300e4c

Comment: Y cuales son los errores que te salen al tratar de instalar? Te sale la pantalla de grub de los instaladores o ni eso?

Comment: Hablando desde mi experiencia personal, al colocar una imagen del instalador en un dispositivo USB (crudo, no en una partición del dispositivo USB, así no va a funcionar), he podido hacer arrancar equipos con instaladores y live distros aunque _creo_ que tenían uefi habilitado.... pero no lo puedo jurar. Por eso pregunto si por lo menos llegaste a ver la pantalla de grub en algún momento.

Comment: Nop, ni la pantalla de grub, lo unico que me sale son las opciones para iniciar, windows 7 y windows 10, pero nada mas

Comment: Ok..... y le estás dando a la tecla durante el boot para cambiar el dispositivo de arranque? En el caso de ese equipo es...... F2 (Fn+F2, quizás?) https://askubuntu.com/questions/582845/im-trying-to-intsall-ubuntu-to-a-samsung-np300e4c-laptop-but-cant-access-bio

Comment: Si, ya intente todas la combinaciones posibles. Antes de elegir que windows iniciar toco la tecla esc y se va a un tipo de "bios" aparece el disco en modo uefi y no aparecen los pendrives, tambien probe con mucho. Posiblemente lo lleve a reparar

Comment: Como estás construyendo el dispositivo desde el que estás tratando de instalar la distro? Y ese dispositivo sirve para arrancar otros equipos?

Comment: No se entiende qué error sale al usar unetbootin, así que no sabemos si la imagen en la USB está bien creada. Tampoco sabemos qué error sale al intentar iniciar desde la USB. Si no has logrado eso, no sirve nada de lo que mencionas. Desactiva el arranque seguro en la BIOS (safe booting) e intenta arrancar desde la USB, que así es que vas a poder instalar la distro que elegiste.

Comment: Intenta desactivar el arranque seguro en la BIOS y activar la compatibilidad heredada.